# WinForms Grid Datasource does not update rows quantity

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, bindingsource

I have pretty simple question.

```
List<OrderTripChangedAlertItem> da = new List<OrderTripChangedAlertItem>();
            da.Add(new OrderTripChangedAlertItem(1, "2", "3"));

            BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
            bs.DataSource = da;

            GridView.DataSource = bs;
```

And class

```
public class OrderTripChangedAlertItem
{
    public int RecordID { get; set; }
    public string RecordInformation { get; set; }
    public string RecordType { get; set; }

    public OrderTripChangedAlertItem(int recordID, string recordInformation, string recordType)
    {
        RecordID = recordID;
        RecordInformation = recordInformation;
        RecordType = recordType;
    }
}
```

Why i have GridView.Rows = 0 ? This is Telerik's grid but i have the same with usual DataGridView.

What is the correct way to fill grid view with generic list ?
Becuase i spent half of day already and cant fill the grid.
I also tried BindingList and Datatable with no luck.

I only was able to write GridView.Rows.Add(1, "2", "3"); and only then to see this record in the grid. Buf of course this is not what i want. I need to bind a list.

PS I even tried some List{string} and DataGridView and also didnt have rows quantity greater than 0.

Comment: Can you step through your code and tell me the `Count` of items in `da`?  It seems like there is nothing for the grid to bind to.  Are you seeing column names and no data?

Comment: da.Add(new OrderTripChangedAlertItem(1, "2", "3")); there is the data always. yes, i can see columns, i generate them by code, not auto.

Comment: It's odd.. but I believe the solution in Jon's update is the proper way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no WinForms binding guru but I've been working through some problems of my own and I wonder whether your problem is be the order of assignment and binding.

I'd try this

```
List<OrderTripChangedAlertItem> da = new List<OrderTripChangedAlertItem>();

BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = da;

GridView.DataSource = bs;

da.Add(new OrderTripChangedAlertItem(1, "2", "3"));
```

so that there's definitely a change to the bound data after the DataGrid has been bound to the BindingSource and is therefore watching for change notifications.

I admit that it seems like your code should work as written because assigning *anything* to the GridView's DataSource property should register as a change, but I'd give the above a try anyway. I've had mixed results with WinForms binding behaving as it "should" do. I prefer WPF binding!

[UPDATE]
You should use a BindingList as your BindingSource's DataSource, and use your generic list as the data for that, so:

```
List<OrderTripChangedAlertItem> da = new List<OrderTripChangedAlertItem>();

BindingList bl = new BindingList<OrderTripChangedAlertItem>(da);
BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
bs.DataSource = bl;

GridView.DataSource = bs;

da.Add(new OrderTripChangedAlertItem(1, "2", "3"));
```

I forget the details, but BindingList implements something nice for List change notifications :-)

Comment: Ah, I just noticed you're not using a BindingList as an intermediate store. I checked some working code of mine and spotted the extra step. Will edit my suggestion with another code sample...

Comment: I still has 0 rows, and so no data in the grid. Dunno what to think